# Existence of weak derivative of $\|x\|^s$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

I am currently reading Chapter 2 from the book Finite Elements by Dietrich Braess. Note that Sobolev Spaces are quite a new concept for me. I am trying to figure out how to approach the following problem (1.11 in the book):

> Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a sphere with the center at the origin. Show that $u(x)=\|x\|^s$ possesses a weak derivative in $L_2(\Omega)$ if $2s>2-n$ or if $s=0$.

I know that on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$, the function possesses strong first order partial derivatives:
$$\partial x_i(\|x\|^s)=s\|x\|^{s-2}x_i.$$
How can I prove that these verify the weak derivative condition:
$$\int_{\Omega}\phi(x)s\|x\|^{s-2}x_i\,dx=-\int_\Omega\partial x_i(\phi)\|x\|^s\, dx$$ for any $\phi\in C_0^\infty(\infty)$? I think the coarea formula may be involved given that the domain is a sphere and we have the norm terms.

Also, can a function possess weak derivatives of higher order but not of first order? Or can I state that a function possesses or not weak derivatives only by looking at first order weak derivatives.

Comment: Basically, the only obstruction is that the (strong) derivative of $|\cdot|^s$ be locally  square-integrable (this is where the condition on the exponents comes from). To make this rigorous, truncate the integral to be over $\Omega\setminus B(0,\varepsilon)$, apply the divergence theorem/integration by parts there and let $\varepsilon \to 0^+$.